# How to detect data type in column of table in ORACLE database (probably blob or clob)?

Tags: oracle, blob, clob, varchar2

I have a table with a column in the format `VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR)`. This column contained a row containing comma-separated numbers `(ex: "3;3;780;1230;1;450..")`. Now the situation has changed. Some rows contain data in the old format, but some contain the following data `(ex: "BAAAABAAAAAgAAAAHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQOUw6..")`. Maybe it's blob or clob. How can I check exactly? And how can I read it now? Sorry for my noob question :)

Comment: Why are you storing data like that at all? You shouldn't store multiple delimited values in a string, the data should be normalised; and each column should have the correct data type, not be shoved into a string column. Anyway... your example doesn't look like a string version of a RAW, so I doubt it's a CLOB or a BLOB anyway, and it would have to be a small one if it was. Where is this data coming from, and why don't you know what it represents when (or preferably before) it's stored?

Comment: This is not my database. I am just importing data from this database. When I encountered this situation, I inquired about the changes and received the answer: "The storage space structure changed to save DB space.". The strangest thing is that the data is saved in different formats. I need to work out a temporary solution.

Comment: OK, aside from questioning their answer which appears to be fairly nonsensical... how do the people you're getting the data from know what it means? They must have a mechanism to convert it, surely; so is there a flag that tells them what the string represents?

Comment: I think you have to look in the sourcecode of the application to get the correct answer. Could be the CHR representation of the values in the csv or something like that...

Comment: Instead of answers, I was suggested not to climb directly into the database but to use the API. I agree with them, but I need a quick temporary solution before I can safely switch to importing data through the API.

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is you really can't. Your column is a `VARCHAR2` so it's all character data. It seems like what you're really asking is "How do I tell if this value is a comma separated string or a binary value encoded as a string?" So the best you can do is make an educated guess. There's not enough information here to give a very good answer, but you can try things like:

1. If the value is numeric characters with separators (you say commas but your example has semicolons) then treat it as such.

   - But what if the column value is "123", is that a single number or a short binary value?
2. If there are any letters in the value, you know it's not a separated list of numbers, then treat it as binary. But not all encoded binary values will have letters.
3. Try decoding it as binary, if it fails, maybe it's actually the separated list. This probably isn't a good one.